# Count numbers of a specific character in a DFS algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, depth-first-search

How can i find a algorithm that count numbers of a specific character in a matrix?
Im thinking a DFS?

the matrix could look like this:

```
xxxxx
x nxx
xx xx
xnxxx
xxxxx
```

And i want to count the numbers of n in the matrix?

Im not good at algorithms so please be gentle with me :)

Comment: To my understanding, DFS is not needed for this. How is the matrix represented? Are you referring to a specific programming language?

Comment: Is this homework? Are you required to use a DFS?

Comment: Im using java ! Its a NxN matrix

Comment: im not requred to use a DFS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char[][] M = new char[][];

init(M);
count = 0;

for each row:
  for each element of the row:
    if M[row][column] == specific_char:
      count = count + 1;

return count;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix[i][j];//matrix 10x10
j = 0;
i = 0;
for(j = 0 ; j < 9; j++){

  for(i = 0; i < 9 ; i++;){

 if(matrix[j][i]  == character){...}
}

}
```